# How to compare one example with a sample of data?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test

I realize that $t$-test are usually used to check for example if a sample belongs to the population, or if two samples are different.

What about if you have a sample of $n=200$ and you want to check what is the probability a new individual example is part of that sample. Or rather I just want to know where in the distribution of the sample the example is!

Comment: Possibly Duplicate question:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232290/probability-that-one-observation-comes-from-the-same-population-as-a-given-sampl

The bottom line is you're going to have to describe all possible distributions from which the new observation could belong to say anything meaningful here.

If your objective is to compare two different distributions to see if they are statistically similar, several tests exists like the Kolomogorov-Smirnov test.

Comment: What do you mean by describe all possible distributions? It is an individual example hence I can only assume about the distribution. I guess what I originally wanted does not really make sense statistically. What I think is more realistic is to assume normal distribution and than just compare where in the normal distribution the example value falls.

Comment: If you wanted to test if your sample could have reasonably been drawn from a normal distribution, you could use the Anderson-Darling test:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test#:~:text=The%20Anderson%E2%80%93Darling%20test%20is,critical%20values%20is%20distribution%2Dfree..

Comment: In my view, NOT a duplicate. Here the reference group has $n=200.$ In the non-duplicate the reference group has $n = 10.$ So the same discussion and answer do not apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is similar to the one in @StatsStudent's link, which you should read.
However, a major, and crucial, difference is that your comparison sample is much larger with $n = 200.$

Suppose you have a normal population $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15)$ and an additional observation $X = 130.$ You can ask how likely it is
that the new observation might have come from that population. A
traditional answer, is that $P(X \ge 130) = P(Z > (130-100)/15 = 2)\approx 0.023.$ So if you interpret this as a P-value you'd say, probably not (if you like testing at the 5% level).

```
1 - pnorm(130, 100, 15)
[1] 0.02275013

1 - pnorm(2)            # std normal w/o extra parameters
[1] 0.02275013
```

Now suppose you have a sample of size $n = 200.$ Unknown to you it's from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15).$ You're willing to assume your new observation is from a population with the same variance as your sample of 200. Then you could do a *pooled* 2-sample t test, and you might
conclude the new observation could have come the same population because the P-value is 0.078 (if you
like testing at the 5% level).

```
set.seed(2020)
x2 = rnorm(200, 100, 15)
t.test(130, x2, var.eq = T)

        Two Sample t-test

data:  130 and x2
t = 1.7697, df = 199, p-value = 0.0783
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.433716 63.535081
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
130.00000  99.94932
```

Somewhat more than half of similar reference groups would lead
to rejection:

```
set.seed(2020)
x = 130
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(x, rnorm(200,100,15), var.eq=T)$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.58711
```

Comment: Note, I didn't read the OP's question the way you worked the second part of your answer (with a sample size of $n=200$).  I read the OP's question as having a sample of 200 and the OP is trying to determine if a new, single observation was drawn from it.  Perhaps the OP could clarify the intent of the question?

Also, what if the OP can't assume normality?

Comment: @BruceEt I think you meant 130 in your example not 135 (value you used in the R computation)

Comment: @Nakx: Right that 135 should have been 130. Thanks. Fixed it.